# Multiple grids on matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm making plots in Python and matplotlib, which I found huge and flexible, till now.

The only thing I couldn't find how to do, is to make my plot have multiple grids.
I've looked into the [documentation](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.grid), but that's just for line style...

I'm thinking on something like two plots each one with a different grid, which will overlap them.

So, for example I want to make this graph:

[Alt text http://img137.imageshack.us/img137/2017/waittimeprobability.png](http://img137.imageshack.us/img137/2017/waittimeprobability.png)

Have a similar grid marks as this one:

[Alt text http://img137.imageshack.us/img137/6122/saucelabssauceloadday.png](http://img137.imageshack.us/img137/6122/saucelabssauceloadday.png)

And by that, I mean, more frequent grids with lighter color between important points.

Comment: it seems you're looking for minor ticks

Answer (score 33, accepted):

How about something like this (adapted from [here](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/major_minor_demo1.html)):

```
from pylab import *
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator, FormatStrFormatter

t = arange(0.0, 100.0, 0.1)
s = sin(0.1*pi*t)*exp(-t*0.01)

ax = subplot(111)
plot(t,s)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(20))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%d'))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(5))

ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(0.5))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(0.1))

ax.xaxis.grid(True,'minor')
ax.yaxis.grid(True,'minor')
ax.xaxis.grid(True,'major',linewidth=2)
ax.yaxis.grid(True,'major',linewidth=2)

show()
```

[image]

Comment: That seems to be exactly what I'm looking for! I'll try it today and mark your answer as soon as it works. Thanks